# Slicing in Pandas Dataframes and comparing elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Morning.  Recently I have been trying to implement pandas in creating large data tables for machine learning (I'm trying to move away from numpy as best I can).

However-I'm running into some issues-namely, slicing pandas date frames.
Namely-I'd like to return the rows I specify and reference and compare particular elements with those in other arrays-here's some a small amount of code i've implemented and some outline

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import math
import random as nd
import numpy

#create the pandas dataframe from my csv. The Csv is entirely numerical data    
#with exception of the first row vector which has column labels 

df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Python\Downloads\Data for Brent - Secondattampatatdfrandomsample.csv")

#I use panda functionality to return a random sample of the data (a subset 
#of the array) 
df_sample=pd.DataFrame.sample(df,10)
```

It's at this point that I want to compare the first element along each row vector to the original data.  Specifically, the first element in any  row contains an id number.
If the elements of the original data frame and the sample frame match up like to compute a 3 and 6 month average of the associated column elements with matching id number

I want to disclaim I'm comfy moving to `numpy` and away from `pandas`-but there are training model methods I hear a ton of good things about in `pandas` (My training is the mathematics side of things and less so the program development).  thanks for the input!

edit:  here is the sample input for the first 11 row vectors in the dataframe (id, year, month,x,y,z)
            id  year  month x         y             z
    0        2  2016   2  1130   343.627538  163660.060200
    1        2  2016   4   859   913.314513  360633.159400
    2        2  2016   5   931   858.548056   93608.190030
    3        2  2016   6   489   548.314860   39925.669950
    4        2  2016   7   537   684.441725   80270.240060
    5        2  2016   8   618   673.887072  124041.560000
    6        2  2016   9  1030   644.749493   88975.429980
    7        2  2016  10  1001   543.312870   54874.599830
    8        2  2016  11  1194   689.053707   79930.230000
    9        2  2016  12   673   483.644736   27567.749940
    10       2  2017   1   912   657.716386   54590.460070
    11       2  2017   2   671   682.007537   52514.580380

here is how sample data is returned given N same n tuple as before.  I used native panda functions to return a randomly generated subset of 10 row vectors out of almost 9000 entries

```
         2  2016   1  633  877.9282175   75890.97027
5185  2774  2016   4  184   399.418719   9974.375000
9441  4974  2017   2  239   135.520851      0.000000
5134  2745  2017   2  187   217.220657   7711.333333
8561  4063  2017   1  103   505.714286  18880.000000
3328  2033  2016  11  118   452.152542   7622.000000
3503  2157  2016   3  287   446.668831   8092.588235
5228  2791  2016   2  243   400.166008  12655.250000
9380  4708  2017   2  210   402.690583   5282.352941
1631  1178  2016  10   56   563.716667  16911.500000
2700  1766  2016   1   97   486.764151   6449.625000
```

Comment: Can you please offer some sample data and desired output? Your question is a little confusing to me at the moment.

Comment: I'd go as far as to say that your question is more than a little confusing.  Read [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MinimalCompleteVerifiableExample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on how to save yourself and others from wasting effort.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly (and who knows if I am), _every_ ID in `df_sample` will be in `df` necessarily

Comment: @CharlieG But then.. how do you have a sample? :P

Comment: Here's an example of the datafram after read in:


erm let me add this to the body for readability


As you guys know the leftmost values are the indices of the data frame-but the first column of the data is the entity id (there are usually 12 entries for each id which range from 2-9000)

Comment: Edited the body with sample data.  Thanks for the patience.  I'll try to clean up the body a bit too

Comment: Ah I was thinking unique ID

Comment: No worries! And Apologies.  If it's any defense I'm up to my ears in cough syrup at work :(.

Back to the question though-the ids are non unique. and I'd like to decry the appropriate positions in the sample array to search for identical elements in the original array and compute averages (and eventually more rigorous statistical modeling) to their associated numerical data.  I'm having some serious issues right now though-and it could be because I'm assuming indexing behaves the same way it does in numpy (which I've been hearing is less easy and elegant than pandas in some respects).

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to decry the appropriate positions in the sample array to search for identical elements in the original array and compute averages (and eventually more rigorous statistical modeling) to their associated numerical data

```
for id in df_sample['id'].unique():
    df.groupby('id').mean()[['x', 'y', 'z']].reset_index()
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want but I'll walk through it to see if it gives you ideas. For each unique `id` in the sample (I did it for all of them, implement whatever check you like), I grouped the original dataframe by that `id` (all rows with `id == 2` are smushed together) and took the mean of the resulting `pandas.GroupBy` object as required (which averages the smushed together rows, for each column not in the groupby call). Since this averages your month and year as well, and all I think I care about is x, y, and z, I selected those columns, and then for aesthetic purposes reset the index.

Alternatively, if you wanted the average for that `id` for each `year` in the original `df`, you could do

```
df.groupby(['id', 'year']).mean()[['x', 'y', 'z']].reset_index()
```

Comment: oh very nice-i see your aim.  

I am trying to ascertain the respective operations under the original data frame-the sample frame was a rather lazy attempt and generating random draws of entities for the sample.

Comment: Sorry-meant to add this to the last edit-is it possible to for the group by function to "group" n desired elements by id?  Or is there a better implementation in pandas?